# Routing Error for [GET] "/auth/facebook"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, rails-routing

I'm using `devise` and `omniauth` gems for authentication. I've followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised) tutorial, but I have `facebook` and `google_oauth2` as providers. The same error is for `google_oauth2`.

`user.rb`:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :google_oauth2]
```

`devise.rb`:

```
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["FB_KEY"], ENV["FB_SECRET"], {
    :image_size => 'large'
    }

  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV["GPLUS_KEY"], ENV["GPLUS_SECRET"], {
      :image_aspect_ratio => "square",
      :image_size => 200
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard omniauth strategy through the gem:

https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

And the best way to do this is follow the gem instructions:

[https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview)